# Почему фраза - "Разверзнутая бездна", безграмотна?

Tags: безграмотность

Почему нельзя написать "Разверзнутая бездна", если речь идёт о развернутой, кем-то, бездне в своём сознании, с помощью исключительно себя, без участия сил самой бездны? Почему нужно писать, либо "Развезнувшаяся", либо "Разверзшаяся" бездна, если в этом случае она сама разверзается, а не кто-то её разверзает? Дело в том, что эта фраза - заголовок текста, который отображает его смысл.

Comment: Поясните, сама форма *разверзнутая* кем-то считается незаконной, или именно сочетание с бездной?  
Вы сами это придумали, наверное.  
> М. А. Шолохов. Тихий Дон. Книга вторая (1928-1940) Может, и исправился бы Максимка, да в бою, начавшемся на подступах к Ростову, колупнула ему пуля голову, вытек на рубаху голубой Максимкин глаз, забила ключом кровь **из разверзнутой, как консервная банка, черепной коробки.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А кто сказал, что нельзя? Такая форма есть: http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C

Причастие страд. прош.времени-разве́рзнутый. Мне нравится:

Звездная улыбка ночи. Голод

И страниц разверзнутая бездна…

С сайта http://www.inpearls.ru/

Comment: Такой формы и там нет. Есть муж.р. "разверзнутый". А "бездна" - ж.р. Согласно рус.яз. можно написать: "разверзшаяся", либо "разверзнувшаяся". http://encyc.mir-x.ru/90182.html Ужас! Видно наша русская грамотность не такая уж и грамотная. Которая, порой запрещает писать грамотно.
Поэтому правильно:
Звездная улыбка ночи. Голод
И страниц разверзшаяся бездна...
Что влечет к тебе так неизбежно:
Тишина, созвездия, твой город....
       А так же
Житейской пьесы, худо-бедно.
Но разве так пал Карфаген?!
Молчит разверзнутая(шаяся!) бездна
И ничего не даст взамен.  http://www.litprichal.ru/work/99878/

Comment: Если есть мужской род, то можно и женский, и средний. А также во всех падежах.

Comment: **Людмила** права, сначала надо узнать, "кто сказал, что нельзя?".

Comment: Разверзнутый-начальная форма, а вся парадигма - полная, пролистала Грамматику 80/словоизменение глагола.http://rushkolnik.ru/docs/87/index-183859-16.html  разверзнуть -4 КЛАСС § 1560. Показатель класса - соотношение "нуль– н,  включает свыше 50 глаг.корней, многие из которых представлены только в сочетании с префиксами: -/бегнуть/,-/вергнуть/ /мякнуть/,/никнуть/, /пухнуть/, /разверзнуть/ (книжн.)и т.д.Значит, возможна и форма страдательного причастия с суфф.-Т-, т.к.нигде нет о недостаточности парадигмы, а в словарях, возможно, нет слова, потому что это книжное , в активный ряд не входит.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всем! Без вас истина бала бы попрана ногами. Прекратил бы её поиски. Искренне прошу извинить меня РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК за не очень умные реплики в его адрес. До недавнего времени, в отличии от издательства, мне и в голову не приходило считать форму "разверзнутая" безграмотной. Но доказать обратное, оказалось делом невозможным. P.S. http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C  Затем + страд. залог = прич.прош.вр. = И.пад. = ж.р.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы кто-то разверзнул бездну, она была бы разверзнутой. Но она разверзлась сама, поэтому страдательное причастие неуместно. Это не всегда строго соблюдается, потому что страдательные причастия легко переходят в прилагательные. Если у человека открытое лицо, это не значит, что он или кто-то другой его открыл. Но слово разверзнутый пока еще явно несет черты именно причастия, поэтому бездна - разверзшаяся.

Comment: Автор вопроса пишет : *если речь идет о развер(з)нутой кем-то бездне в своем сознании*, **с помощью исключительно себя**... В чем же состоит пафос ответа???